# unable to get d3js tree to display

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3js to create a tree graph with two nodes connected to each other. My JS is as follows:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var nodes = [{"id":"1","name":"a"},{"id":"2","name":"b"}];
var links = [{"source":0,"target":1}];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width", width);
svg.attr("height", height);
svg.append("svg:g");

var tree = d3.layout.tree();
tree.size([width, height]);
tree.nodes(nodes);
tree.links(links);
```

The JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eeLfog4m/

Unfortunately, nothing is coming up on the page and I'm unsure as to why. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not enough to run the layout, you also need to add the elements. See e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Comment: Now everything is bunched up at the top: https://jsfiddle.net/eeLfog4m/1/

Comment: how come you want a tree layout with data like that ? Looks like you need: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Answer (score 0):

Your data isn't set out like a normal tree layout. Take Lars' example in the comments : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Data looks like :

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },.....
```

You sure you dont want force layout ? : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Here is the force with your data : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/s6fug9q6/

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var nodes = [{"id":"1","name":"a"},{"id":"2","name":"b"}];
var links = [{"source":0,"target":1}];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width", width);
svg.attr("height", height);
svg.append("svg:g");

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);


  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You can position these nodes explicitly.